# Receive payment without 3rd party API

Tags: address, api

So is there anyway to generate address and then check the address to see if enough fund is sent and enough confirmation without using any 3rd party API?

Works on software written in C# or/and Web PHP.

Comment: You could set up a Bitcoin Node and then control/query it over JSON-RPC from your app

Comment: @RaghavSood thanks, I was thinking about that but I'm unsure how to check the transaction confirmation and amount receive using it